# PDF417 generated by ZXingObjC is unreadable sometimes

Tags: ios, zxing

I am trying to use ZXingObjC to generate PDF417 barcodes for my iOS app. I've got it all working, sort of. It generates the barcode and displays it on the screen. Unfortunately, sometimes the barcode is unreadable by a 'real' scanner.

If the encoded text is all just upper or lower case characters, for example, "Now is the TIME for all good men", then the generated barcode is perfectly readable.

However, if the string contains just one number, anywhere in the string, then the barcode is unreadable. It's just not recognized by the 'real' scanner.

Other encoded strings produce barcodes that decode as gibberish.

I am wondering if I need to do more configuration to generate PDF417s properly. For example, it says on the ZXingObjC website "Use UTF-16 for all PDF417 characters". How would you do that?

Are there other configuration options I should be setting?

I know this is an obscure topic, but hope someone has some knowledge about this. Thanks in advance.